# Pouring liquid from one cup to another

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

So, the title basically explains it. I am trying to create an animation in which I want to pour liquid from one cup to another but I don't know my way about it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? where are you finding problems?

Answer (score 0):

A litlle bit more information of what you tried and where you got stuck wwould be great - there are a lot of Tutorials out there that can help you.
Once you get stuck and can`t figure it out update your question.